# Vb6: name of the activex control

Tags: vb6, activex

Anyone know what is the name (if exist) of the control used for display the properties?

[image]

Apparently it is some modified list object but i wish to know if exist a control that do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many commercial ones like this: 
http://www.innovasys.com/products/proplist/overview.aspx

Comment: thanks but this particullary is discontinued, though  i found that http://xceed.com/SmartUI_ActiveX_Intro.html. thanks

Comment: We've used the SmartUI for years, and it is an excellent product.